# Running Mono Android samples

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I downloaded Mono software (http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) and the samples from the xamarin website (http://samples.xamarin.com/Android). When I run the samples, after choosing the emulator from the list (I choose MonoForAndroid_API_10) it is loading the screen, but I don't see out output of my sample!!!

I am just running the simple Hello Droid sample..

Other emulators aval are,
MonoForAndroid_API_10
MonoForAndroid_API_12
MonoForAndroid_API_14
MonoForAndroid_API_7
MonoForAndroid_API_8

I even tried to choose the different emulator, but no use.

Comment: They are extremely slow to initialize the first time you run them. I left mine run and walked off and 10mins later, while watching TV it eventually popped up. Not sure if it is the same for you but they do take a long long time to start first time.

Comment: I left it for more than 30 mins.. All I can see the menu icons on the emulator.. not the output of my app.

Comment: Any one knows why its not showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my self.. Just need to click 'OK' button on 'Select Device' window.